# React increment / decrement function only 1 up or down allowed

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component with a couple a function to increment or decrement a number when the up or down button is clicked.

This is what I've done:

```
...

 this.state = {
      score: 50, //The initial number can only go up or down 1
      clicked: 0,
    };

...then

increment() {
    if (!this.state.voted) {
      this.setState({
        score: this.state.score + 1,
        voted: this.state.voted = 1,
      });
    }
  }

  decrement() {
    if (!this.state.voted) {
      this.setState({
        score: this.state.score - 1,
        voted: this.state.voted = 1,
      });
    }
  }
}
```

Right now as soon as I click any of the buttons which run either functions it will stop functioning but I need it to work as long as it doesn't go up or down more that 1

*So 50 can go to 51 when clicked increment and decrement can only go down to 49*

How can I do this?

Comment: You somehow need to keep track of the starting score of the `state`. Then your `if` statement checks if the current score is +/- 1 instead of `voted`

Comment: Why don't you disable the button right after was clicked, I mean, if the increment button already sum 1, just disable it, letting only the decrement button being able to be clicked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a flag checking if a vote has already occurred, just check that the value is within the correct range. That means you only increment if < 51, and only decrement if > 49.

```
this.state = {
  score: 50, //The initial number can only go up or down 1
  clicked: 0,
};

increment() {
  if (this.state.score < 51) {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score + 1,
  });
}

decrement() {
  if (this.state.score > 49) {
    this.setState({
      score: this.state.score - 1,
    });
  }
}
```

If the score could be any value, then simply keep another property, such as `defaultScore` which initializes to the same value as `score`, and your checks would become `score < (defaultScore + 1)` and `score > (defaultScore - 1)`.